# Не понятно тестовое задание на Frontend разработчика

Tags: javascript, frontend

Получила тестовое задание на позицию Junior Frontend разработчика. Не совсем понимаю, что и как требуется сделать.

> Необходимо реализовать SPA с заметками на VUE.js.
> Приложение должно содержать 2 страницы:
>
> 1. Список заметок с пагинацией. В списке - название заметки и дата.
> 2. Детали по каждой заметке с её редактированием.
>    Переход между страницами должен осуществляться без перезагрузки.

**В этой части все понятно**

> После обновления страницы данные не должны потеряться.

**Здесь появляется первый вопрос: как это реализовать в Frontend. Что хочет видеть работодатель?**

> В качестве результата нужно прислать исходники и собранный проект так, чтобы можно было протестировать проект без деплоя.

**Понимаю что нужно сделать, но не понимаю как. Т.е. для сохранения заметок нужно добавлять их в базу данных, как отправить готовый проект с БД?**

Есть ли какие-нибудь ресурсы для изучения этого?

Comment: использовать gulp или webpack  дальше всё написано ... записать заметки в localstorage но перед этим сделать так что бы эти заметки можно было реализовать так же как и саму запись в локальное хранилище ...ну и всё это на vue

Comment: @MaximLensky зачем тут что-либо использовать если в целом речь идет про один html, один 1 css и два js файла?

Comment: @teran  ну vue без других файлов ? и плюс хотят исходники - вроде на webpack надо - ну мне давали такое задание и я именно так делал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> После обновления страницы данные не должны потеряться.

В этом случае от Вас требуют и проверяют знания работы с LocalStorage и Vuex (или LocalStorage можно заменить на пакет [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate), тогда только Vuex можно обойтись). Как реализовать - описано целиком и полностью в [документации по Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/).

Как вариант, Вы можете разработать API с базой данных, но вряд ли от Вас это требуют, поскольку хотят проект без деплоя.

> В качестве результата нужно прислать исходники и собранный проект так,
> чтобы можно было протестировать проект без деплоя.

В целом, требуют запустить команду `npm run build`, запечатать все файлы из папки и отправить (только вряд ли node_modules им будут нужны, а то они весить будут нехило). Т.е точка входа по index.html, на нём работает Vue уже в режиме SPA. Закомпиленный проект потянет за собой файлы уже сразу после распаковки (проверяющие это задание у работадателя странные конечно, раз не могут развернуть проект, это уже первый звоночек, но ладно).

---

Это очень простое задание, если Вы хоть как-то разбирались с Vue, Vuex и т.д. Для выполнения задания надо просто прочитать документацию.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду разбираться)